# how to get location using Latitude and Longitude in java?

Tags: java, html, location, latitude-longitude

I am getting longitude and latitude from JSP using HTml5 in Servlet,  i want exract exact location(City name,Country name) using these two parameters.Any suggestion to Resolve this ISSUE.

Comment: You need to provide more information, what you've given is too broad.

Comment: simple i want location using longitude and latitude.nothing more than that

Comment: what do you mean exact location? what is your issue?

Comment: issue is like that, i have longitude and latitude with me,i want to find location of these longitude and latitude.

Comment: latitude and longitude IS the location, do you mean you want a city? or a state? country?

Comment: sorry.yes i want city name,Coutry name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Google geocoding service to get the location by passing a pair of latitude and longitude...it returns the response as accurate as possible in the form of JSON or XML whichever you prefer..

Here is a [link](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true_or_false) the sensor parameter is a must so make sure for a browser you say false for a device having it pass true..

so just use the HttpURLConnection class and read the response from this url and you will get the response. Parse the response for formatted_address object.

This contains the address you need.

its awesome..

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this service http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

Comment: How to get current location latitude and longitude in java? with out passing any input. If possible please let me know